# git branch with no commits

Tags: git, bash

You would think this would not be a common use case, but I create new `git` repos pretty frequently.  Essentially, I have a shell script that stores the current branch into `$CURRENT_BRANCH` via:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null > /dev/null
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

This works well, even in non-git repos (which is the idea).  However, one case where it complains *a lot* is a git repo that has no commits.  Specificially I get:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
>   Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   'git  [...] -- [...]'

This raises at least two questions:

1. Why does this error display even though I am redirecting both `stderr` and `stdout` to `null` via `2>/dev/null > /dev/null`
2. How can I get the current branch name even if there are no commits?

Comment: You are using two commands and only one command is redirecting the output.  I think the ```fatal:``` is coming from the second

Comment: @Alex ordinarily I would think you would be right, but running line #2  (the second command, redirection and all) *still* seems to include the fatal error output

Comment: Because of `-e`, the first `rev-parse` makes the script exit when *not* in a git repo.  But when you *are* in a git repo, the *second* `rev-parse` spits out the error (only the first `rev-parse`'s stderr is being ditched).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an empty repo, `HEAD` is attached to a branch that doesn't exist, so `git rev-parse` can't get a rev [that explanation isn't necessarily what causes the code to complain].  But `git symbolic-ref` doesn't ever care about the SHA, so

```
git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD || echo HEAD
```

with an attached `HEAD` won't look any farther than that, but the `git symbolic-ref` fails if `HEAD`'s not attached to a branch so the `echo` preserves your current behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the `__git_ps1` command?
It was initially made to add these kind of information to PS1, nut you can use it from prompt as well.

I'm using this to show the current git branch in my prompt:

```
PS1="\$(__git_ps1 '(%s) ')${PS1}"
```

Just call this to print the current branch:

```
__git_ps1 '%s\n'
```

The argument is a formatted string. `%s` gets replaced by the branch's name.
The command does not give any output, if `$PWD` is not inside a git repo.

You need git's bash-completion to have that version defined.
It's located here `/usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-prompt`.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of repository you have created ? Is it a bare repository and is it that you are running these commands in the bare repository? Does running "git branch" show you any branch ?

In a bare repository, it won't fetch you any useful information and is not advisable to run any direct operation in it.Ideally, I would clone a bare repository and then do an empty commit in it to get started so that the branch name appears(by default "master") would be created. Now if you wish change the name of branch. Coming to you errors you faced, I could reproduce it at my end when I cloned a bare repository and had not created any branch in it.

Or, did you create an orphan branch when you faced this issue.